# It is possible to install pgAgent on Heroku Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, pgagent

I just need to know if it is possible to install pgAgent on Heroku Postgres.

Could someone explain me his experience about pgAgent on Heroku?

thanks